# timeBased and time

Tags: r, xts

```
a <- c("12/4/2010 9:30:00","12/4/2010 9:31:00","12/4/2010 9:32:00",
       "12/4/2010 9:33:00","12/4/2010 9:34:00","12/4/2010 9:35:00")
b <- strptime(a,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

> time(a)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 1 6 1

> time(b)    
Error in hasTsp(x) : invalid time series parameters specified

> timeBased(a)
[1] FALSE

> timeBased(b)
[1] TRUE
```

Is there any way to make it work for both `time` and `timeBased` functions, meaning no error when using `time` and returning `TRUE` with `timeBased`?

Comment: Where did you the timeBased function from? My R2.14 installation does not recognize it by default. In addition, it would help if you could provide more background as to why you want to do this.

Comment: timeBased is from xts package, i need my data to pass through timeBased to create xts data format and also to work fine with time to create run applyRules (quanstrat if im not wrong)

Comment: `time` apparently expects a vector, but `b` is a list (of type `POSIXlt`), not a vector. You could try to convert it to a `POSIXct` object: `time( as.POSIXct(b) )`.

Answer (score 1):

`time` does not do what you think it does.  It is generic, so it does different things depending on what type of object you give it, but in general, it gives you the indexes and it is not much different than `index`

```
> require("xts")

> x <- xts(1:6, b)
> time(x)
[1] "2010-04-12 09:30:00 CDT" "2010-04-12 09:31:00 CDT"
[3] "2010-04-12 09:32:00 CDT" "2010-04-12 09:33:00 CDT"
[5] "2010-04-12 09:34:00 CDT" "2010-04-12 09:35:00 CDT"

> index(x)
[1] "2010-04-12 09:30:00 CDT" "2010-04-12 09:31:00 CDT"
[3] "2010-04-12 09:32:00 CDT" "2010-04-12 09:33:00 CDT"
[5] "2010-04-12 09:34:00 CDT" "2010-04-12 09:35:00 CDT"

> timeBased(x)
[1] FALSE
> timeBased(index(x))
[1] TRUE
> timeBased(time(x))
[1] TRUE
```